# Git-lfs: Not in a git repository error when downloading cBioPortal files onto Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, git-lfs

I want to download the `gbm_tcga_pub2013` dataset from cBioPortal (https://www.cbioportal.org/study/summary?id=gbm_tcga_pub2013) using `git-lfs` onto Google Colab. I receive a `Not in a git repository.` error

```
!curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
!sudo apt-get install git-lfs
!git lfs install --skip-repo --skip-smudge
!git clone https://github.com/cBioPortal/datahub.git
!cd datahub
!git lfs install --local --skip-smudge
!git lfs pull -I public/gbm_tcga_pub2013
```

Traceback:

```
Not in a git repository.
Not in a git repository.
```

Even though I was able to change directory to `/datahub`, my working directory as per `pwd` is still `root`.

Comment: Each `!` command is run in a separate environment. `!cd datahub` will, in that envirnoment, change into the `./datahub` directory. Then it's done, so that environment gets discarded. You're back *outside of* the `./datahub` directory. The two `!git` commands afterward run in the *wrong directory*. (So the error has nothing to do with Git, really. How you want to go about fixing this depends on other items, but in general you need to do both Git commands in the correct subdirectory.)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from `!cd datahub` to

```
%cd datahub
```